# Accessing another collection in MongoDB's map reduce

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I would like to access another collection from the map function, so that I can do a lookup on the key and perform some aggregations. Can I access any collection using `db.collection_name` or something similar in the BSON code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you try this locally it will work. However, this fails completely in a sharded scenario because the collection or the data in the collection will not be local to the shard.

It's also bad practice because the M/R can cause cascading queries that can be hard to trace.

If you are encountering this problem, you have a few optiosn:

1. **Denormalize the data**: If `map` on collection `A` needs fields `x,y,z` from collection `B`, then copy those fields into `A`. Yes, it's not normalized, but MongoDB is not a relational database, it's not intended to be normalized.
2. **Multi-part M/R**: In many cases you can accomplish the same result by performing a few different operations and writing the results to a single collection. So maybe you do a M/R on `A` first and then you loop through the output and update with data from `B` in a separate script/process.

I have seen both options used. I have even seen #2 converted into a simple `for` loop that handles both parts at the same time. I have successfully replaced some M/R jobs with simple `for` loops and upserts.

Comment: Also note that accessing another collection won't work even locally as of Mongo 2.4; the ability for a mapReduce to access other collections has been removed.  See the [release notes](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/release-notes/2.4/#additional-limitations-for-map-reduce-and-where-operations)

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible because it would break in a sharded setup. Map/reduces can only use the collection they're invoked on.